# Finding integration by substitution.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

$$
\int_{-\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}2\,}\,}^{\sqrt{\vphantom{\large A}2\,}\,}
x\sqrt{4 - x^{4}}\,{\rm d}x
$$
I find the answer $0$ by substitution $x^{2} = u$, but it didn't make sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No substitution is needed.  The integrand is an odd function of $x$ and you are integrating on an interval that is symmetric about $0$. Therefore the integral is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

make sense with this substitution x=2 sin a